# How to remove json elements from response after sequelize creates a db record?

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Using sequelize, I can create a `product` in my database using the `Product` modek, but I want to edit the json response, removing the updatedAt and createdAt elements. How would I do this?

My code:

```
router.post('/products', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    }).then(
        product => res.status(200)
            .json(product)
    )
});
```

When calling localhost:3000/products with this body:

```
{
    "name": "A Book",
    "price": 10.99,
}
```

I get this in response:

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "A Book",
    "price": 10.99,
    "updatedAt": "2018-06-26T20:09:38.643Z",  <-- Remove?
    "createdAt": "2018-06-26T20:09:38.643Z"   <-- Remove?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick) pick().

If your response is,

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "A Book",
    "price": 10.99,
    "updatedAt": "2018-06-26T20:09:38.643Z",
    "createdAt": "2018-06-26T20:09:38.643Z"
}
```

Try, `var result = _.pick(response, ["name", "price"]);`

```
router.post('/products', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    }).then(
        product => 
            var result = _.pick(response, ["name", "price"]);
            res.status(200).json(result)
    )
});
```